# Ninject: How to use interception with conventions binding

Tags: vb.net, ninject, aop

My MVC 4 service has this binding:

```
        kernel.Bind(Sub(x)
                        x.FromAssembliesMatching("*").
                        SelectAllClasses().
                        BindDefaultInterface()
                    End Sub)
```

Also, the service only has a reference to a contracts project, which contains all my interfaces.
When the Web API service is called, ninject scans the assemblies for the matching concretes and spits back the object, filling in the constructor bindings.

I want to intercept method calls on domain model methods to handle errors, log, and benchmark where appropriate.

Do I have to create a separate module to handle that?
I don't want to have references to ninject in my domain project

Answer (score 4):

Reference `Ninject.Extensions.Interception` and for example the dynamic proxy extension. Then. Do the following:

After `BindDefaulInterface()`

Add

```
.Configure(b => b.InScopeOfYourChoice().Intercept().With...)
```

That's it